# Apps Script - some run, some don't

Tags: google-apps-script

[image]So I have a code that pulls NBA prop bets - I have a code that runs for rebounds, points and assists. It is supposed to load into the spreadsheet in each individual tab. When the code was first created, it ran fine. Now, only the rebounds code runs... the points or assists tab does not.

I'm not sure why 2 of the 3 are not running. *** Disclaimer - I am not very good at coding, kind of trying to self teaching, so I'm sorry if its a dumb question. ***

Here is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12qWi9cRoKMFLpAPhQ31p6sETXI4LvQ3-zXF5RBO8i4w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share all the codes as code blocks not as image so we can easily copy your code and replicate your issue. If needed, you can also share a sample/copy of your spreadsheet with the script you are using.

Comment: Sorry about that! Adding it to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are using the same function name across all your 3 functions. This is causing the confusion on the apps script, even though they are in different .gs files you can't have the same function name. What you can do is rename these 3 functions then call them all in one function:

```
function SPORTBOOK(){
  SPORTBOOKAssists();
  SPORTBOOKPoints();
  SPORTBOOKRebound();
}
```

[image]

Or another approach is, since your codes are repetitive you can just put them all in one function where you are changing the URL or have the 3 URLS and 3 sheets created in one function before setting the values to the sheet.

Comment: Thanks so much Logan! The renaming of function worked! I'll continue learning and work towards making it all in one function, but for now, that worked. You are amazing! Thanks!